# Configuring rsnapshot to only backup local file systems

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

I'm currently using rsnapshot to backup a server farm where NFS is used heavily. Unfortunately, the current setup has us backing up the same files multiple times due to the NFS mounts.

For example, /etc/rsnapshot.conf has this:

```
backup backupuser@machine1:/local_directory/       machine1
backup backupuser@machine2:/exported_directory/       machine2
```

Now, machine1 has /local_directory/exported_directory mounted -- so I end up with backups of both machine1/local_directory/exported_directory **AND** machine2/exported_directory.

While I could work around this by either mounting things differently on the clients or by manually excluding the directories, I'd rather find a cleaner approach (which is probably a rsnapshot or rsync option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I knew I should've perused the man pages one last time before posting :)

It's -x or --one-file-system option to rsync.

```
  -x, --one-file-system
              This tells rsync  not  to  cross  filesystem  boundaries   when
              recursing.   This   is  useful for transferring the contents of
              only one filesystem.
```